# Почему не работает if or jquery?

Tags: javascript

Есть следующий код

```
$(document).on('change', 'select[name=category]', function() {

    console.log('change');

    var id = parseInt($(this).val());

    // console.log(id);  

    if (id != 1 || id != 2)
    {
        console.log('true');

    }
});
```

Если id = 1 или id = 2 условие все равно выполняется.

Comment: надо ставить and :)

Comment: Вы не верно составили условие, оно всегда true

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`||` истинно если хотя бы одна из частей истинна.

Если id = 1, то id != 2, правая часть истинна -> `||` возвращает `true`. и наоборот.

Вам нужно `&&` - оно будет истинно только если id != 1 **и** id !=2.

Comment: Спасибо. Странно, но это работает.

Comment: @Гость: да что ж в этом странного-то?

Comment: Дополняю ответ Павла рекомендациями. Вот вам видеоуроки по javascript'у от ребят из LoftBlog'a: [Основы javascript](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY4rE9dstrJymG1GyPLgOKsJNq9r-p6pX) и [Продвинутый javascript](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLY4rE9dstrJzNRmAeTHXAlT7lJFC2YjDg)

Comment: @Гость вас могут заинтересовать [законы Де Моргана](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Законы_де_Моргана).